# How do file copies work from one vm to another vm when using vmware with a nas

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage

EDIT: Editied my original question to clarify what I was asking for based off of the answer Zac67 answer

If I have two VMs in vSphere, VM A and VM B, with virtual hard drives on the same NAS and I copy a file between them will the bytes of the file be copied from the NAS to the VM's hardware and then sent back to the VM to be written? I was wondering if vmware attempted to do any type of optimization where if it is virtualizing all the hardware that is part of the transaction (all the NICs in this case) will it just copy the bytes from one virtual hard drive to the other virtual hard drive without every sending the bytes to the physical hardware VM A and VM B are running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file is copied from guest to guest the host just sees disk operations and network traffic.

The underlying 'read disk data on VM A' and 'write disk data on VM B' cannot be related to the network traffic - this would require the host to know about and understand all guest actions in detail.

It's the same with the NAS/storage - there's a read operation somewhere and a write operation somewhere else. Whether these two actions are related and what kind of processing takes place in between is far beyond the scope of the storage.

The key to understanding what's actually going on is to think of layers. Each layer has its own purpose and doesn't (need to) care what's going on in the other layers.

Essentially, each guest already implements several layers:

- the application that's copying the data
- the DOS processing the file open, read, file create, and write requests
- the file system mapping these requests to block storage
- the block storage driver handing over the actual read and write requests to the (virtual) disk hardware
- the SMB client accessing the network share (assuming Windows guests)
- the intermediate network layers
- the virtual NIC sending and receiving network packets

The host's role is to provide the VM with virtual hardware (CPU, RAM, storage, NIC) that is actually shared with other VMs and possibly even implemented elsewhere in the network (network storage).

Edit: Using the storage API is something different. However, since the host doesn't have access to (nor understand) the guest file level you can only copy files on the VMFS level easily.

Copying on guest file level would involve dismounting the VMDKs from the guests, figuring out what goes where (filesystem analysis), copying the required blocks, and adjusting the destination file system accordingly (probably easier to move the VMDK temporarily).

Instead of copying the required blocks through the API it may be possible to use the API to copy it directly (I'm not a developer) - this could in fact instruct the NAS to do the copying without host intervention.

Comment: Wouldn't this be do able from vmwares end since they will know all the hardware they are virtualizing and the virtual hardware would be capable of using vmwares API to translate network traffic for a file copy to a vmware payload that tells the virtual hard disk what data to copy internally? I guess the only problem at that point is not knowing the contents of the packets. Even if they know it is going to another machine they are virtualizing but they cant say "this is a file copy from a virtual disk to another virtual disk so move it internally." Is that the limitation?

Comment: I'm a developer and I am just starting to work with our systems team in  a more dev-ops role so I really appreciate answer what is probably a very ridiculous question. After seeing your answer I think my problem is I'm thinking in terms of very high level API's as opposed to the lower level network communication protocols. Again thank you for your answer and sorry if my question in my previous comment and my original question are very green.

Comment: I've added the API variant to my answer above, it doesn't fit in a comment.